How to deploy Angular App on JBoss 7.1 application server
We have created Angular App.  But we are getting 403 Forbitten error after deploying on JBoss.
We have created Angular App. Then build application using "ng build" command which created dist folder. After building application we can create war file using D:\Work\Angular_Workspace\newapp\dist\newapp>jar -cvf mynewapp.war * command and deployed war file to JBoss. But we are gaetting 403 Forbitten error.
